# facebook like button url

Tags: ajax, facebook-like

I'm using this code for facebook like button:

```
   <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.mysite.com/#work2.html"
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"
    style="border:none; width:450px; height:80px"></iframe>
```

If I try to access the link from facebook after I clicked the like button It gives me just "www.mysite.com"
If I try to access it manually, I mean to copy and paste the url it works.
My website is ajax driven.
How can I make the  "#" work for facebook ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change it to a ? rather than a # for facebook since it doesn't do hash tags.  In your app, you can check for either a hash or a query string parameter to do same thing

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to make this...  Could you give me some indications? Thanks!

Comment: href=http://www.mysite.com/#work2.html  VS  href=http://www.mysite.com/?page=work2.html

Comment: So, you are saying to change the href in the iframe with:             "?page=work2.html". I've maked this but it's not working because my website is ajax driven and it doesn't load it properly without the "#"

Comment: Again, you will need to change YOUR code to make it work with either ? or #

Comment: This is why I've said in my first comment that I don't have any idea how to change the code to make it work with "#" or " ?"

Comment: We cannot program it for you.  You will need to learn how to code.

Comment: I don't ask it for a specific solutions just some indications or some resources maybe to learn from it. Thanks !